# find functions within specific criteria (Big O notation)

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I have to find two functions $f(n)$ and  $g(n)$

criteria for $f(n)$ are:

- $f(n) \in O(n \cdot \log(n))$
- $f(n) \notin Θ(n \cdot \log(n))$

criteria for $g(n)$ are:

- $g(n) \in Ω(n)$
- $g(n) \notin Θ(n)$

I'm new to this, so this might be a trivial problem. But I just can't find a solution. I know:

- $f(n) \in O(g(n)) \iff 0\le \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \lt \infty$
- $f(n) \in Θ(g(n)) \iff 0\lt  \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \lt \infty$
- $f(n) \in Ω(g(n)) \iff 0\lt  \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \le \infty$

Comment: Check with $f(n)=1,g(n)=n^2$.